# Developing an Augmented Reality app for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

We will be developing an Augmented Reality Android app for out project.

I've watched several tutorials on YouTube about AR, I see them use `Unity`, `Vuforia`, `ARToolKit`, `OpenSpace3D`, etc. I've also watched videos on how to use `Android Studio` in creating an android app.

When they create the AR scene they want on, for example, Unity & Vuforia, they export it to an Android device and then they run their project on the device. They did not need to use Android Studio for that. When they click on the app on the device, it automatically opens up the AR camera, ready to read the markers, and that's it.

The app that we are going to do has multiple features, one of those features is the AR Camera. I was wondering if there was a way to create a menu for our app, so that the user has the option to choose what to do.

I know that I can create menus in Android Studio, and I can create an AR scene in Unity. BUT I'm not sure if I can put the AR scene that I've made, into the menu I made in Android Studio. I do not know if it is possible. Maybe there is another way of doing this?

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Off topic . Voted to close .

Comment: here's a sweet tutorial on AR with Unity and Vuforia https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLe9ToTE7BA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: yes, you can do that. In this case all functionality will be based on Unity (including menu screens).

Workflow is roughly be as follows:

- create menu scene(s) as needed in Unity
- create AR scene based on Vuforia plugin
- on user action in menu scene switch to AR scene

Then for production

- switch output to desired platform (Windows, OS-X, Android, iOS)
- generate output

In case of Android you can generate the complete APK ready for publishing through Google Play. No need for Android Studio.

Be warned that you will have some kind of a learning curve though if you haven't worked with Unity and Vuforia before.

Oh and you must obtain the right license(s) for your situation from both Unity and Vuforia.